# Create multiple pages pdf

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

I successfully created PDF in android but its showing data on one page but i am using scrollView in my layout means i have many line's data. so if i have small data then its looking cool but if i have large data then it shrink the data and set it on one page it looking so congested, so i want automatically create pages as per requirement of data.

this is my onclick:-

```
downBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(scrollLayout, scrollLayout.getWidth(), scrollLayout.getHeight());
            createPdf();
        }
    });
```

this is createpdf method:-

```
private void createPdf(){
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    float hight = displaymetrics.heightPixels ;
    float width = displaymetrics.widthPixels ;
    int convertHighet = (int) hight, convertWidth = (int) width;
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(convertWidth, convertHighet,1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, convertWidth, convertHighet, true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0 , null);
        document.finishPage(page);     
    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath") String targetPdf = "/sdcard/pdfexample.pdf";
    File filePath;
    filePath = new File(targetPdf);
    try {
        document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    document.close();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You can save your pdf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    openGeneratedPDF();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(convertWidth, convertHighet,1).create();
```

Hare you mention pageno one only so you have increase page no requred by data to store in one page so use any loop to increase page no